# receiving error (internal server error) when sending Ajax request on Asp.NET Web Forms Endpoint

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am sending ajax request in asp.net i get this error

> POST http://localhost:1549/AdminArea/Roles.aspx/Create 500 (Internal
>   Server Error)

it is with Master Page Also shown code is in individual page  `Roles.aspx`
my HTML Code

```
<form  id="FormSave">      
  <input type="text" name="txtName" id="txtName" required="required" 
                class="form-control"/>                                      
 <input type="radio" name="Status" value="1" checked="checked"/> Active
 <input type="radio" name="Status" value="0"/> In-active
 </form>
```

Javascript Code For Sending Request

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $("#BtnSave").click(function () {
                var jsonText = JSON.stringify({ Name: $("txtName").val(), Status: $("Status").val() });
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "Roles.aspx/Create",
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                    data: jsonText,
                    dataType: "json",
                    success: function (response) {
                        alert(response);
                    }
                });
            });    
  });
  </script>
```

SERVER SIDE C# SCRIPT /// IN Roles.aspx.cs file

```
[WebMethod]
public static string Create(string Name, string Status)
{
        return "Hello " + Name + "With " + Status;
}
```

I want to alert this Hello Name  With Status

Comment: Don't use JSON, just send values in normal url-encoded format (jQuery can do this for you if you just supply it with a regular JS object in the "data" argument). That should help. If you do want to use JSON, then the webmethod will need to accept a DTO object containing the relevant properties, rather than separate individual string arguments. You can't deserialise a single JSON object into multiple variables. There's a mismatch between what you're sending and what the server is expecting

Comment: Also did you check the server logs to see if it logged any exceptions relating to the 500 error?